# The admin layout is showing in xml format

Tags: admin

I am using magento 2.3 when i run the deploy command my admin layout is show in xml  format is any one help me to solve this problem..[image]

Comment: that's definitly not XML

Comment: Looks like language placeholders. Are you using a non-default language?

Comment: No, I am using the Default English only. But still not getting why it showing like this?

Comment: @PhilippSander, you have any idea why it like this?